# Spring security with jwt get all user logged

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

i would like to display all users logged in my application i use spring security with jwt authentifcation,

when i tried to get all users spring security give me empty array

```
@Autowired
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

@GetMapping("/userConnecter")

public List<String> userConnecter(){

List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();

List<String> usersNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Object principal: principals) {
    if (principal instanceof User) {
        usersNamesList.add(((User) principal).getUsername());
    }
}
return usersNamesList;
```

}

```
@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}
```

I think the problem is related with injection dependency.

is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (principal instanceof User) {
    usersNamesList.add(((User) principal).getUsername());
}
```

can you please verify `User` is org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User ?

also, try by adding

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

 }
}
```

Comment: i have the same result [] empty array

Answer (score -1):

the problem i use stateless for jwt

http.csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement();

```
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
http.formLogin().permitAll();
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll();
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/Automobiles/**").permitAll();
```